# OAUTH 2 for API and app

Tags: api, authentication, oauth, oauth-2.0, authorization

We've set up a REST API for our web application and are also making an app for several devices. Now I'm looking at ways to secure it, and OAuth 2 seems like the logical way to go, especially since we want to open up the api for our users later on. However, being totally new to this I've been reading up on OAuth 2 and there are a few things I'm having trouble finding answers for.

The solution we want to use is quite similar to Googles OAuth 2 for devices. When you open the app for the first time, you are presented with a code. In our web application, you then log in to your account, where you enter the code and the device gets added as a trusted device (here you can later revoke access if necessary). The app polls for an access token, which it will receive when it's been added to the user's account in the web application. The user should then have access to his/her content through the app.

So far, it seems that OAuth 2 with client credentials grant could be what we should be using with our trusted app, but as the user have to be identified and will also be sending data to the system I'm unsure if I'm on the right track?

Answer (score 1):

The initial flow using the special code sounds specific to your application. In other words, such a flow is not defined in OAuth 2.0.

[Client Credentials Grant](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-4.4) is allowed only when the [client type](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-2.1) is 'confidential'. So, if your application is to be installed onto Android and/or iOS, Client Credentials Grant should not be used.

I think that the initial flow should be implemented in a special way specific to your system (= irrelevant to OAuth 2.0) and that the flow involving user interaction should be implemented based on a flow defined in OAuth 2.0 (either [Authorization Code Grant](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-4.1) or [Implicit Grant](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-4.2)).

If the special code presented to the user on the first invocation of your application is uniquely generated and assigned to the user and if you plan to use the code as 'client_id', it may be possible to use 'response_type=none' which is defined in [OAuth 2.0 Multiple Response Type Encoding Practices](http://openid.net/specs/oauth-v2-multiple-response-types-1_0.html), [4. None Response Type](http://openid.net/specs/oauth-v2-multiple-response-types-1_0.html#none). In the section, a scenario like below is described as an example.

> One scenario is where a user wishes to purchase an application from a market, and desires to authorize application installation and grant the application access to Protected Resources in a single step. However, since the user is not presently interacting with the (not yet active) application, it is not appropriate to return access credentials simultaneously in the authorization step.

Comment: Hi Takahiko, wil you be able to comment on below question related to OAuth 2.0 approach, if I will be using what is mentioned in below post or is there any better way. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44620839/what-is-the-right-oauth-workflow-for-3rd-party-rest-apis